# Square API paymentform not populating input fields on Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, square-connect

I am integrating squareup api in my wordpress woocommerce site I set SqPaymentForm in my plugin
But it only shows form labels not input fields. something like this:

[image]

I set it in my custom template it works fine but not in my plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your javascript is being fired before your plugin has rendered on the page. You can try loading your script in the footer with `wp_enqueue_script('squareup-paymentform', 'https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform', array(), false, true)` or call `paymentform.build()` after your page has loaded. Take a look here for more information: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form/#generatingpaymentform

Comment: yes console returns error but the squareup's javascript was getting perfectly as per their sequence...the main problem is iframe is not loading...

Comment: What is your error? Can you share an example of your code?

Comment: I am getting error something like this : [error](http://prntscr.com/dic5t8)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. So far everything looks like it should work, but your form is clearly not building right. Have you changed the code from the sample form?

Comment: Actually it looks like this is a Wordpress issue. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: this.iframeControllers.cardNumber.element.contentWindow is null i getting this error while submit button press can u tell me the reason

Comment: The payment form probably hasn't loaded before you try to click the button, is your code live somewhere I could see?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, I was able to enter my card details and submit the form without error.

Comment: Nonce was not generated, anyway i fix it..the problem was my settimeout function not getting sqPaymentForm i need to set it globaly